# Which has better in-flight entertainment for a 7-year old and a 4-year old? KLM or Emirates?

Tags: airlines, klm, emirates

Which has better in-flight entertainment for a seven-year-old and a four-year-old?

KLM or Emirates?

Comment: You should specify if you are travelling business class or coach.

Answer (score 9):

**Emirates**, hands down.  Emirates [ICE](http://www.emirates.com/au/english/flying/inflight_entertainment/ice.aspx) has a huge TV in every seat with 600+ channels including a big kids section, and they only have new planes.   On KLM, if you end up on their ancient MD-11s, you'll be squinting at [a screen the size of a postage stamp in the front of the cabin](http://airchive.com/html/cabins-and-cockpits/klm-mcdonnell-douglas-md-11-cabin/klm-mcdonnell-douglas-md11-world-business-class-2012/26010) (and that's in *business class*!).

In general, Emirates is the better airline in every possible dimension: better seating, larger screens, better food, better service, better hub airport, etc.

Comment: You're exaggerating the case of KLM. KLM has only 10 MD-11, and only on some routes. I flew on one of them in Economy on Amsterdam-Montreal in 2013 and it was totally fine. Maybe the screens are smaller (seatguru says 9 inches) but it's not as bad as you sound!

Comment: Also in the picture you linked to, there are personal screens (or something that looks like personal screens).

Comment: I have to give another vote to Emirates. The ICE kids content kept my little one quiet for the most part of a 16 hour flight.

Comment: @Vince: you're right, looks like they've installed personal TVs in most (all?) MD-11s now.  But I stand my ground on everything else.  Sure, there are worse airlines than KLM...  but there aren't many better than Emirates.

Comment: Oh Boy ! Ama flying KLM in a week. I better get them ipods packing with the best country music.